# Export SQL objects using dbatools

Tags: powershell, dbatools

I am trying to export objects from SQL databases (including SQL Agent jobs) using the following scripts:

```
$SourceServer = "***";
$folder = "c:\temp\sqljobs\"

Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance $SourceServer | ForEach-Object { Export-DbaScript -InputObject $_ -Path ($folder + $_.Name + “.sql”) }



$SourceServer = "***";
$SourceDB = "***";
$folder = "c:\temp\sqltables\"

Get-DbaDBTable -SqlInstance $SourceServer -Database $SourceDB | ForEach-Object { Export-DbaScript -InputObject $_ -Path ($folder + $_.Name + “.sql”) }
```

The objects are being correctly exported but a folder is created in the root folder with the objectname and inside I have the sql script with the server name and timestamp.

I was wondering if I can generate the sql script itself directly to root folder without creating the folder with the object name.

Comment: Script you've shared appears incomplete. Where does `$folder` come from?

Comment: I've updated the code.

Comment: You probably want to use `-FilePath`, not `-Path` and.. best use straight quotes instead of those curly so-called 'smart-quotes' in code.

Comment: Thank you Theo for your inputs. That was the missing piece. Thank you so much.